# Add additional 32bit repositories

Tags: repository, 32-bit

Can somebody let me know how I can add additional 32bit binaries in my ubuntu machine. or please let me know how I can create new repository.

Comment: What do you mean by "additional"? Repositories are added and managed (mostly) independently of architecture. Of course you need to enable additional architectures before you can use them (from all repositories configured previously and in the future alike).

Answer (score 1):

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
```

That should enable the 32bit libs along 64bit ones.